# Move to next item in ng-repeat item in items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a carousel that I should render 2 items in each ng-repeat cycle like this:

```
<div  owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="item in (filteredItems = (items | filter:query))" class="item">
          <a ng-href="/#/{{Page.Culture+'/live/'+item.id}}">
            <div class="tv-show-box one-row">
              <div class="tv-show-box-cover">
                <ul>
                  <li>{{::item.name}}</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <img ng-src="{{::item.image_name}}" width="220" height="148"  alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
          </a>
          <--PART2: Item must go to next Item for this part -->
          <a ng-href="/#/{{Page.Culture+'/live/'+item.id}}">
            <div class="tv-show-box one-row">
              <div class="tv-show-box-cover">
                <ul>
                  <li>{{::filteredItems[$index + 1].name}}</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <img ng-src="{{::filteredItems[$index + 1].image_name}}" width="220" height="148"  alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
```

I means in Part2 define in code, I need to move to next item before ng-repeat is called again, I'm using $index+1 but it's not good for me,

I want to it to permanently move to next item not just accessing to it

Does it have something like item.Next() or something?

Comment: Not sure about `item.Next()` or something like that, but I think I would group my data (i.e. `filteredItems`) in groups of two, then you can iterate over each group and print item one and two.

Comment: how should I do that? do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

You could for example try something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0">
   <td class="text-center">{{item.id}}</td>
   <td class="text-center">{{items[$index + 1].id}}</td>
</tr>
```

it may be enough to do the trick for you :)

**Edit:**

For 3 items you could do:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0">
    <td class="text-center">{{item.id}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{items[$index + 1].id}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{items[$index + 2].id}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for 3 different carousel in one page, the second one mix up!!! is that because of using $index? I don't get it, the second carousel index set like 0,2,4,6,8 .... and it doesn't show anything

Comment: When I changed the $index % 2 ==0 to $index % 3 ==0 now index are like 0, 3, 6, 9 .... Odd! there is something changing the index I suppose or there is a conflict on indexes! have you faced this before?

Comment: If you set it to $index % 3 == 0, you should get indexes 0, 3, 6, 9.. so it's correct, you can then use items[$index + 1] and items[$index + 2] to get the remaining items. Doesn't it work?

Comment: No, I just set it to 3 for test, in index 2 for the second carousel it didn't work, it look like that all of the indexes are 0,2,4,6,8 and it doesn't show any of them because of ng-if, where are the 1,3,5,7 gone then?

Comment: I attached another example that works, check if it helps. Ng-if is used to filer rows other than 0, 3, 6, 9. You have to access rows 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8 by yourself with  items[$index + 1] and items[$index + 2] to get everything from the list.
So to clarify, in the first ng-repeat run (index = 0) you will get items 0, 1 and 2, for the second (index = 3): 3, 4 and 5 and so on.